# sliderInput in Shiny app in R

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple question for which I haven't find a solution by far.
In ui.R if the app has a `sliderInput` widget like following:

```
sliderInput(inputId="frame",label="Frame ID", min=172, max=356, value=172)
```

How can I specify the min and max values from the data frame in server.R? The data frame in server.R is subsetted when user selects a value from `selectInput` widget. For each case I want the min and max to change based on a variable in that data frame.

Is there any example? Please help.

Comment: http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use renderUI to create a reactive control:

ui.R

```
uiOutput("myControl")
```

server.R

```
myDf <- reactive({
# code that subsets data.frame based on input[['somevars']]
})


output$myControl <- renderUI({
  mydataframe <- myDf()
  myVar <- mydataframe[, c("appvar")]
  minmax <- range(myVar)
  startVal <- sample(do.call(":", as.list(minmax)),1)
  sliderInput(inputId="frame",label="Frame ID", min=minmax[1], max=minmax[2][, value=startVal)
})
```